# React - How to get an id and use it to delete

Tags: reactjs, axios, crud, http-delete

So in react I made a button to delete some data so I need to get teh car by id and remove it by using react js axios so the response I got is an empty array so can some one help me please.

Here is the code :

in service data file :

```
get(id) {

  return http.get(`/get/${id}`);
}
delete(id) {

  return http.delete(`/delete/${id}`);
}
```

**Component.jsx**

```
 this.state = {
        idCars: null,
        carName: "",
        carModel: "", 
        cars: [],
        submitted: false
      };

     
    }
    getCar(idCars) {
      DataService.get(idCars)
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            cars: response.data
            
          });
          console.log(response.data);
          
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
   

    componentDidMount() {
      
      this.getCar(this.props.match.params.idCars);
      this.retrieveCars()
    }
 deleteC() {    
     

      DataService.delete(this.state.cars.idCars)
        .then(response => {
          
          this.props.history.push('/Classement');
          this.refreshList()
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
 render() {
      const { cars } = this.state;
           return (      
            <div ><tbody>
                    {
                      cars.map(data => (
                        <tr >
                        
                        <th scope="row">{data.idCars}</th>  
                      
                      <td>{data.carName}</td>
                      <td>{data.carModel}</td>
                      <td>
                 
                      <button  className="btn btn-danger"  onClick={this.deleteC}>
                        Remove
                      </button>
                        </td> 
            
                      </tr>
                      ))
                    }
```

And doesn't remove nothing, how can I fix this guys

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your DeleteC function tries to read:

```
this.state.cars.idCars
```

But this.state.cars is an array so idCars is only defined for a given index such as in:

```
this.state.cars[0].idCars
```

What you could do is modify your onClick behavior for this:

```
onClick={() => deleteC(data.idCars)}
```

This way the deleteC function will be called with the idCars of the selected row.

Comment: I tried to pass id on click but it returns id as an undefined here is the error I get in the console : vendors~main.chunk.js:91980 DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/delete/undefined net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES And the error loops

Comment: That's working now... thank you sooo much